# Intellij Idea 14. All tooltips disappear after moving mouse

Tags: intellij-idea

In new 14 version of Intellij Idea I'm encounter problem: all tooltips which are triggered by highlighting elements are disappear when I slightly move mouse (and then appear again). I think the correct behavior is that tooltip should not disappear as long as my cursor is over that element.

To be more clear, I mean *all* tooltips in IDE. For example error/warning description tooltip, button description tooltip and all others tooltips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a known and already reported bug, which is not fixed yet. You can see the issue here, in Jetbrains [bug tracking system](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)

> [IDEA-70943 New tooltips are broken](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-70943)

Comment: its still doing it now for me.

Comment: Then please report it using the link above including your IDEA version and system information.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ 14 behaves the same way for me. 

 In IntelliJ 13 this does behave different as I just tried, so it might be a bug.

 As you didn't ask anything directly this is all I can say.